# angular-ui/bootstrap: Is there a way to get something like "onDialogOpen"?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I open a modal dialog in my controller with ui-bootstrap and I need to know when the dialog is opened (partial html is added to the dom). In my particular case I need that to have OpenLayers find the corresponding map div.

I can't use the promise object returned by dialog.open() because "success" is called when the dialog is closed.

I have two controllers so far

- MainCtrl
- DialogCtrl

Is there a way to figure out the event mentioned above?

Thanks in advance!